# What font can I use for a Japanese book?

Tags: fonts

(I already asked the question on [graphicdesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/what-font-can-i-use-for-a-japanese-book) but people redirected me here.  I guess there are people with that kind of expertise here.)

I have a PDF book to be translated in Japanese, and what wondering which fonts to use. My main languages are French and English and I have no experience with asian fonts. I would not be able to say if a font is OK for reading a Japanese book or not.

For example, in English or French books (Latin-alphabet typography), the font types normally used are serif font (Times Roman, Caslon, Bodoni and Garamond). Other font types would not be appropriate.

Is there such thing as Serif font or Roman fonts in Japanese?

Do you have any suggestions for a common Japanese Roman font?

Comment: sawa put it a little harshly, but the layout for Japanese books is different than English, so you'll have to pay attention to more than just the font.  For example, manga goes right-to-left top-to-bottom, which is pretty different from a Latin setup for similar materials.  I would strongly suggest seeking out someone who is fluent in the language.  As for your specific question about fonts, sawa's answer does list those.

Comment: Even though you we redirected here, this type of question is off-topic and will probably be closed.  See the [FAQ](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.  Sorry.

Comment: I think there is an intersting typography question here so I'd suggest a rewording to "Is there something analogous to 'serif vs. sans serif' in Japanese typography?"

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/10714/looking-for-a-japanese-font-to-match-garamond/10715#10715.

Comment: The original version of this got answered already - [What font can I use for a Japanese book?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5126/what-font-can-i-use-for-a-japanese-book) - so now this has been migrated back here, it's a duplicate of that one... (hopefully we're a bit more co-ordinated now than we were in 2011...)

Answer (score 5):

There are counterparts to such things, but as the people on the graphicdesign website already mentioned, it will not be of any help to you to know which font to use since you do not seem to have any basic knowledge about the Japanese language. Do you know which of the long vowel characters to use in which mode of writing (vertical or horizontal)? Do you have the proper knowledge about 禁則処理? Probably not. Even if you choose the correct fonts, the product you come up with will probably be strange and full of mistakes to the level that it will look comical to a native speaker. The best idea is to let a native speaker of Japanese do all of that instead of you trying to do it.

Just for reference, the counterpart to serif is usually 明朝体 (or 教科書体 in some cases), and the counterpart to sans-serif is usually ゴシック体 or ゴチック体. If you cannot read these font names in Japanese, you should not attempt to use them.

Comment: What made you think that 教科書体 is a counterpart to serif font?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto It is used in the main text in documents. The usual choice is either 明朝体 or 教科書体. And the decoration to a stroke in serif corresponds to the はね, かえし, etc of these fonts.

Comment: I have never seen a document whose main text is typeset in 教科書体 other than textbooks.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto It is not as popular as 明朝体, but I have still seen it. And if the former is replaced by the latter, it would not look so different. But I will put it in parentheses to weaken the claim.

Comment: Come on.  If [明朝体](http://www.akibatec.net/wabunfont/category/min.html) and [教科書体](http://www.akibatec.net/wabunfont/category/kyokasho.html) do not look very different to you, you do not know typefaces.

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto They don't. I am not an expert in typefaces, but at least, I know about タイポス, リュウミンライト, Nimbus Roman fonts etc., and about モリサワ etc. I also have studied on my own about the METAFONT type setting language that accompanies TeX. I am not saying that they are the same. But the difference is smaller than the difference between them and a ゴシック font. And if you read paperbacks (文庫本) from several different publishers, you will notice that several of the fonts that I mentioned are used in the main text.

Comment: Which of the fonts you mentioned is 教科書体?

Comment: 教科書体 usually is slanted upwards, and is as written with penbrush i.e. the stroke thickness from original brush writing is preserved, while 明朝体 only has the serifs, and the strokes are just thin lines. Formal or techical print-text will usually use 明朝体 (except for captions or titles, in ゴシック), where it's sometimes , while 教科書体 is just as its name implies.
EDIT: oh, and try referring this http://www.shosha.kokugo.juen.ac.jp/oshiki/ronbun/kyokashotai99/kyotai99.html

Comment: I really like your last paragraph but would love to know more about that. What makes those counterparts?